# Unable to fetch UNSEEN Sent Emails from IMAP (GMAIL)

Tags: python-3.x, email, smtp, gmail, imap

**Requirement:** Fetch all unread mails from Sent Mail box (replies to mails sent by me)

**What i've tried:**

With the below script i'm able to get all the sent mails

```py
...
imap_client.select('"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"')

imap_client.search(None, "(ALL)")
```

But with the below script i'm not getting the unread mails in the sent mailbox

```py
...
imap_client.select('"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"')

imap_client.search(None, "(UNSEEN)")
```

How to get the unseen messages in sent mailbox?

Comment: Generally new sent messages are already marked \Seen, so there are no unseen messages.  Are you removing the \Seen glad yourself?

Comment: i'm asking about replies for sent mails

Comment: Replies to send mails do not appear in the Sent Mail box.  All new messages are in the INBOX (unless you have scripts or filters moving them.)